# Yii2 Assets are not loading in case of .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, yii2, assets, yii2-advanced-app

I am redirecting users from wildcard sub-domains to a specific sub directory using mod rewrite rule while not changing address bar url. I was able to do it but with some issues with my yii2 project. After redirecting no assets is loading. No CSS or JS, nothing. I am guessing this has something to do with relative paths of assets. How can I solve this problem? Do I need to change @webroot alias, if so how can I do that?

Comment: you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: You should probably open up your browsers' development console and see what URLs its attempting to load. `@webroot` is the directory where the bootstrap file is loaded from, so that will probably be correct. It will be `@web` that is wrong I think. By default that is set to `Request::getBaseUrl()`

Comment: @anubhava although `<base href="/" />` resolves the problem of loading assets but it messes up internal linking of the framework. Internal `<a href="">` also changes and does not work intendedly.

Comment: Are you redirecting all the requests made to subdomains?

Comment: Yes @zazu. My project resides in sub directory and I want to give the feel of using sub domain to the users.

Comment: Watch the console of your browser, what does it tell about missing files?

Comment: Well the CSS and JS files are linked for example `/subdirectoryname/backend/web/assets/87782a2a/css/bootstrap.css', I guess the paths are appended to the sub domain name. As the project is not at that sub domain they are not linked.